# Why is my button duplicating when I append it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my button should only append once for each word it finds, but somehow it appends more then once. I have no idea what could cause this to happen and therefore I posted a bit more code then just the button piece and the append piece. I think something is going wrong right before I append or so? Here you have a picture to see how it looks: [image]    as you can see, 4 words... but 10 buttons or so whilst it should be 4.

```
function createExercise(json) {
const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
var exer = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'row'
  })
  .append(
    $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'col-md-3'
    })
    .append(
      $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
      })
      .append($('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-3 testforbutton',
       // text: "(button here)"
      }))
      .append($('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
        'id': 'eenwoordlol[' + ID123 + ']', // note the brackets will need to be escaped in later DOM queries
        text: exercise.word
      }))
    )
  ).append(
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'col-md-9',
      text: "(4 x col-3 here)"
    })
  );

$("#exerciseField").append(exer);
ID123++;
$('.testforbutton').append(getAudioForWords());
});
}

createExercise(fakejson);


function getAudioForWords() {
    var audioBtn = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary fa fa-volume-up sound'
   });
   return audioBtn;
 }
```

Comment: oh oke.. quick question tho: why post my JSON (just curious).

Comment: you're appending button on class, that might be a problem, `$('.testforbutton').append(getAudioForWords());` will append button on every `.testforbutton` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, each iteration of *exercises* will add a button to all existing `testforbutton` element, duplicating buttons in previously added rows.

Just limit your selector to search of the `testforbutton` element in the current `exer` element

```
exer.find('.testforbutton').append(getAudioForWords());
```